# Hitting concurrent Request Limit!

Tags: force.com-sites, governorlimits, concurrency

Because of COVID-19, a new urgent web-form has been created in Salesforce Service to receive the  customers' requests.
This new web-form was published yesterday through Sites and many requests are being received since the beginning, we are capturing and monitoring an average of 2600 requests per hour, but we have found that in many cases the concurrent request limit is being exceeded and this error is being displayed to customers.

```
Unable to Process Request
Concurrent Request limit Exceeded.
```

Does anyone have expertise on this as to how this should be debugged through Event Monitoring?How We can find the problematic code?We also want to know how many requests are getting unattended because of time out.Does that get logged somewhere?

Comment: Are you calling out to another system?

Comment: which licensed are you using?

Comment: No,We are not making a call out.Also we are on Unlimited edition of Salesforce.

Comment: Though Salesforce has increased the limit, I would like to understand if there is any way to know what requests were dropped and what were successful?Can Event monitoring do it or is there any other option where it is logged in real time?